# Opening network file from excel vba code on MAC uses offline file

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I have excel with macros run in Mac OS.
One of the macros uses *Workbooks.Open* to open a file in network folder (a SharePoint site).
It works fine if there is connection into the network.
Also it works fine if the user of the Mac profile runs the macro for the **first time** with the **network connection on or off**. If there is no connection Mac returns error like it should when run first time.
However the problem is that after the user has succesfully used the file (macro) with the connection on once then *Workbooks.Open* does not return any error when running the macro second time and the network connection is down. 
I added exit sub command right after the Open method and could see that there is same network file open on excel with status of 'Offline file'. That file was the same as the one previously opened when using the macro with network open for the first time. However the file was not fetched from the network drive as this time there is no connection to network.
Tried to find the file from Mac file system, without success.

What creates the offline copy and where is it stored?
How to delete the offline file via vba code or how to prevent excel (or Mac) from creating it ever again?

Br,

MikkoT

Comment: I have not worked with Sharepoint but I guess this is not a programming question. It's about SharePoint Settings? Not sure but does [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/change-where-you-work-on-files-that-you-check-out-from-a-sharepoint-library-HA010208583.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable oplocks in the SMB protocol.

> Oplocks are opportunistic locks, a client-side performance enhancement
>   that requires cooperation between a Windows client and the SMB
>   service. If SMB service supports oplocks, the client can request to
>   cache a file locally, in order to perform read and write operations on
>   the cached file rather than directly on the server. This saves network
>   bandwidth and increases performance for the SMB client. If another SMB
>   client requests access to the file, the SMB service notifies the
>   holder of the oplock, and that client should write changes from its
>   cache back to the SMB service. The SMB service does not let another
>   client have access to the file until the first client has finished
>   writing.

[image]